# Restrict AWS Cloudfront requests to specific URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have set up AWS Cloudfront to serve files from S3.

My S3 bucket objects are successfully being served via Cloudfront on a subdomain `https://files.example.com`

The files are publicly accessible and have paths like `https://files.example.com/my-document.pdf`

Is there a way to restrict access to the Cloudfront endpoints so if the request is from a specific page `https://www.example.com/gated-page` the user is successfully directed to `https://files.example.com/my-document.pdf` but if the file URL is manually entered into the search bar, or if a link to it is on another page, the user gets redirected or blocked?

Comment: You can use [WAF to validate the Referer header](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [signed links](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html). It is another way to limit access to links through Cloudfront that could work depending on your exact use case.

Another option would be to create a [Cloudfront function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) that inspects the referer header and responds with a 403 error or a redirect if the header doesn't match.

And like someone wrote in a comment, you could use the AWS Web Application Firewall. That would probably be the most expensive option if you are not already using it.

Comment: Thank you! Cloudfront functions is an interesting possible solution that looks a bit simpler to use than Lambda functions for this use case. I'm testing it now.

Do you know if signed links would allow the files to be served from the same simple URL (e.g. `https://files.example.com/my-document.pdf`) without a query string attached?

Comment: I think Cloudfront functions would be easiest if you know some JavaScript.

Signed URLs changes the URL, but there is something called signed cookies (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html). that could work.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because WAF worked immediately for me and produced the intended blocking for all non-matching referer's.